# Chord-spelling change in Chopin's Mazurka Op. 24 n.4

Tags: chords, chord-theory, chopin

In the manuscript of measure 138 (marked *mancando*) of his Mazurka, Op. 24 n.4, Chopin crosses out the (same) chord on the third beat and respells it—I assume in preparation for the key change that begins in the next measure):

[image: Manuscipt]

(*Note that after m.1, Chopin does not repeat the 5 flats at the beginning of every line of this Mazurka.*)

I believe that most editions subsequent to the Frist French Edition stay true to this:

[image]

However, Klindworth (1880) in his Complete Edition ignores Chopin's correction and keeps the chord unchanged:

[image: Klindworth]

I have two questions:

(1) To my ears, the change to the major actually starts on the *second*, rather than the first, beat of the next measure (139), so why does Chopin anticipate it in m. 138?

(2) If I am correct, is this Klindworth's reasoning, or is he making some other formal/notational point by keeping the spelling unchanged?

(Klindworth also starts the *mancando* a measure earlier.)

All quotes from IMSLP.

Answer (score 1):

1. Even though the change to major isn't confirmed until beat 2, it does happen (abstractly) on beat 1, with a clear phrase break beforehand. Therefore, the change is signaled in measure 138, but only on the final beat.

2. I suspect Klindworth just found it easier to read to keep the chord the same, and that the signal of the tonal shift wasn't needed.